# Turn on flash/torch on WinRT app in Windows 8.0

Tags: c#, flash, visual-studio-2012, camera, winrt-xaml

In a Windows 8.0 app we want to enable the flash/torch when we take a picture. The app is written in C# and targeted for Windows 8.0. In the SDK for Windows 8.1 some changes were made to access the LED flash http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.torchcontrol.ASPx.  For now we don’t want to upgrade to Windows 8.1 on our tablets (and Visual Studio 2013). So we are looking for a solution to enable the flash in Windows 8.0.

We know it is possible to enable the flash, we have some app that use it. There is also some C++ code which states there are some possibilities to do something with the LED flash. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj151590(v=vs.85).aspx

Did someone managed it to enable the flash/torch in a Windows 8.0 app? Or does someone know how to set specific properties which are available in C++?

Comment: Maybe try `VideoDeviceController`'s `Get/SetProperty`? You'll need to find the device property id though.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately there finding the device property is hard: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b98156d8-b811-414a-b2ab-9570c8f49627/how-to-use-videodevicecontrollergetdevicepropertystring-propertyid?forum=tailoringappsfordevices. But it gives new posibilities.

Comment: With VideoDeviceController.GetAvailableMediaStreamProperties(MediaStreamType.VideoPreview) I get a long list with GUIDS, but I cannot figure which ones I need.

Comment: I don't know if MediaStreamProperties is the right one. Maybe try using the property names from the C++ link you gave with regard to LED flash?